# Why in Javascript 0.1 + 0.2 is equal to 0.30000000000000004?

Tags: javascript

[image]

I would like to know why this number's sum is equal to 0.30000000000000004 ??

Comment: It's not an issue with JavaScript. It's with binary format.

Comment: I know that this is not an issua. I would like to know why it is ?

Comment: This is called Floating-Point Anomaly and it refers to the fact that in binary floating-point, only fractional values of the form `i * (1/2)^j` (where i and j are integers) can be represented exactly.  So `0.5`, or `0.375`, etc., can be represented exactly but all other decimals, such as `0.2` and `0.3` cannot and when you combine them in various ways, it soon becomes evident that they are only approximate.